# My code of C++ shows a runtime error with no output

Tags: c++

I tried to solve the following problem:
Given a string, find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters.

Examples:

- Given "abcabcbb", the answer is "abc", which the length is 3.
- Given "bbbbb", the answer is "b", with the length of 1.
- Given "pwwkew", the answer is "wke", with the length of 3. Note that the answer must be a substring, "pwke" is a subsequence and not a substring.

I basically created two additional functions.

1. notin to check whether x is in a string s
2. longest to output the largest string in a array of strings.

I can’t seem to find any error in my code.

```
class Solution
{
public:

    int lengthOfLongestSubstring(string s)
    {
        string x;
        int i;
        vector <string> t;
        x = s[0];
        for(i = 1; i < s.length(); i++)
        {

            if(notin(x, s[i]))
            {
                x = +(s[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                t.push_back(x);
            }
        }
        s = longest(t);
        i = s.length();

        return i;
    }
    bool notin(string s, char x)
    {

        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {
            if(s[i] == x)
            {

                return false;
            }

        }
        return true;
    }
    string longest(vector <string> t)
    {
        string g;
        g = t[0];
        for(int i = 0; i < t.size(); i++)
        {

            if(t[i + 1].length() > t[i].length())
            {
                g = t[i + 1];

            }
        }
        return g;
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you tell me what kind of runtime error you are getting?

Comment: This is a problem at Leetcode. It just says runtime error with no output.

Comment: Firstly, you should figure out how to reproduce this problem on your computer. Then, pop it into your debugger or use some other method of debugging such as print statements to debug your code.

Comment: @FeiXiang Thankyou. I would do that.

Comment: @blastoise Usage of `std::set<char>` makes this much more easier than your attempt.  You wouldn't need to write functions to check if a character has already been seen, as the `set` would tell you immediately if the character has been seen already.

Comment: In addition, your `lengthOfLongestSubstring` function fails due to undefined behavior if the string is empty.  You attempt to access `s[0]`, which may not exist.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Usage of set<char> is a great suggestion. Thankyou. Can you describe how to avoid the problem of accessing s[0] in case of empty string?

Comment: @blastoise At the beginning of the function, check if `s` is empty, and just return 0 to mean there is no length.  As to `std::set<char>`, you could write the entire assignment in a function of less than 20 lines or so using `std::set`, and just adding characters to the set until you discover a character is already in the set (and thus doing a line or two of basic logic now that you've discovered a new start of the string).  But I am reluctant to post that as an answer, since this is an "online judge" question, and anyone doing a search would link to it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thankyou. The solution are actually available but I personally feel I learn more when I discuss with people. And that's what happened. Thankyou for your help.

Comment: Can someone explain why this question was downvoted? I am now unable to ask new questions for a day because of this :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in your longest() function.

```
for(int i = 0; i < t.size(); i++)
{
    if(t[i + 1].length() > t[i].length())
    {
        g = t[i + 1];
    }
}
```

If `i == t.size() - 1` then accessing `t[i + 1]` would give a segmentation error.

Besides, I think you meant to do this instead:

```
if (t[i].length() > g.length())
    g = t[i];
```

Comment: Yes. After making the corrections it solved my problem. Thankyou :). But my logic I guess is still somehow wrong and I need to check it again because it's not outputting the right answer. :)

Comment: You are over-complicating a simple problem here. Try to use the 2-pointer technique.

Comment: Can you describe a little how to use that here? @KonaeAkira

Comment: Wow.That was neat. Thankyou. I searched a lot online but I can't understand one thing though. Here cnt being representation of a array of numbers, how are you able to do ++cnt. Also how are you able to use alphabets as indexes like str[i] - 'a' ?I mean indexes have to be numerical right?

Comment: Each element in a string is a `char`. In C++ the `char` type is treated as an 8-bit integer.

Answer (score 0):

In your function longest(), you use a vector t with size, say n. And you run the loop from 0 to n-1. But the problem is when you use t[i+1]. During the final iteration, it evaluates to t[n], which is illegal. Because the vector contains elements from 0 to n-1, right?

You can rectify it by changing the loop to

```
for(int i = 1; i < t.size(); i++)
    {

        if(t[i].length() > g.length())
        {
            g = t[i + 1];

        }
```

Also, you can see that I've changed the if condition. There's a problem with your condition. 
Consider the vector {"abcd", "ab", "abc"}. In the first iteration, "abcd" will be stored in g. But during the consequent iterations, since length("abc")>length("ab"), "abc" will be stored in g. Resulting in the function not returning the longest string.
Hope it helps